# Javascript printing on Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have some code in a webpage which generates a table that should be printed on a page with just that table on it.

This used to work fine in chrome, until recently, but now ONLY works in Microsoft Edge (Which would be fine if all the computers in our warehouse was on windows 10, but they are not, and cannot) - So I need desperately for this to work in Chrome, or as a last resort, internet explorer.

Here is the code that generates the tables:

```
<div id="printthis" style="display:none;width:95%;">
<div style="width:95%;border:2px groove black;display:none;">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/theme.css">
<table>
<center>
<p><? echo $parseDay . " - " . $leads[$_GET["line"]] . "'s Line"; ?></p>
</center>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered" style="font-size:12px;width:95%;">
<tr>
<thead>
<th width="125px">Name</th>
<th width="50px">Job</th>
<th>Notes</th>
<th align="right" width="50px">Emergency</th>
</thead>
</tr>
<?
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check))
    {

        $explodeAT = explode("|", $row['AT']);
        $explodeNotes = explode("|", $row['Notes']);

        if((((strcmp($parseDay1, 'Mon') == 0) && (strcmp($explodeAT['0'], 'Absent') == 0))
            || ((strcmp($parseDay1, 'Tue') == 0) && (strcmp($explodeAT['1'], 'Absent') == 0))
            || ((strcmp($parseDay1, 'Wed') == 0) && (strcmp($explodeAT['2'], 'Absent') == 0))
            || ((strcmp($parseDay1, 'Thu') == 0) && (strcmp($explodeAT['3'], 'Absent') == 0))
            || ((strcmp($parseDay1, 'Fri') == 0) && (strcmp($explodeAT['4'], 'Absent') == 0)))
            || (((strcmp($parseDay1, 'Mon') == 0) && (strcmp($explodeAT['0'], '') == 0))
            || ((strcmp($parseDay1, 'Tue') == 0) && (strcmp($explodeAT['1'], '') == 0))
            || ((strcmp($parseDay1, 'Wed') == 0) && (strcmp($explodeAT['2'], '') == 0))
            || ((strcmp($parseDay1, 'Thu') == 0) && (strcmp($explodeAT['3'], '') == 0))
            || ((strcmp($parseDay1, 'Fri') == 0) && (strcmp($explodeAT['4'], '') == 0)))) 
        {
        //if absent or unmarked, don't include. 
        } else {
        //if anything else, include.
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th width="125px">'.$row['Name'].'</th>';

        echo '<th>'.$row['Job'].'</th>';

        if((strcmp($parseDay1, 'Sat') == 0) || (strcmp($parseDay1, 'Sun') == 0)) {
            echo '<th>Today is not accounted for.</th>';
        } else {
            if(strcmp($parseDay1, 'Mon') == 0) {
                echo '<th>'.$explodeNotes['0'].'</th>';
            } else if(strcmp($parseDay1, 'Tue') == 0) {
                echo '<th>'.$explodeNotes['1'].'</th>';
            } else if(strcmp($parseDay1, 'Wed') == 0) {
                echo '<th>'.$explodeNotes['2'].'</th>';
            } else if(strcmp($parseDay1, 'Thu') == 0) {
                echo '<th>'.$explodeNotes['3'].'</th>';
            } else if(strcmp($parseDay1, 'Fri') == 0) {
                echo '<th>'.$explodeNotes['4'].'</th>';
            }
        }
        echo '<th><center><div style="width:15px;height:15px;border:1px solid black;border-radius:2px;"></div></center></th>';
        echo '</tr>';

        }
    }

?>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Which works EXACTLY the way its meant to, it generates fine for Microsoft Edge, and if I display the divs they generate fine on the page.
The idea is that it is hidden on the page but when a button is pressed it opens the div in its own window and prints that.

Here is the javascript (Which is where I believe the problem lies, but I could be wrong, I'm not that great with javascript.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printthis()
    {
     var w = window.open('', '', 'width=800,height=600,resizeable,scrollbars');
     w.document.write($("#printthis").html());
     w.document.close(); // needed for chrome and safari
     javascript:w.print();
     w.close();
     return false;
    }
    </script>
```

I just simply do not understand why this works fine in Microsoft Edge and not in Chrome or IE.

If any other information is needed to help me resolve this, I would be more than happy to supply it.

Here are some pictures:
In edge:
[image]

Which is exactly what I want.

Now, in chrome it gets a little weird. At first I get this dialogue:
[image]

but if I play around with the destination, and change the way the file saves, I get this diaogue:

[image]

Comment: Does it display at all in Chrome? Do you see any errors in the Developer Console (hit F12 to check)?

Comment: Is the use of the [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) in `javascript:w.print();` valid? This is not a loop, so the label is at least meaningless.

Comment: MikeC There are a few errors, but none of them even remotely correlate to the printing code.

Kay - I'm not sure, is there any way I can check myself on that.

About to upload some pics of what I get in edge versus what I get in chrome.

Comment: If you're getting any kind of Javascript errors then that will cause the JS to halt and nothing will happen.

Comment: @MikeC I can confirm none of the errors are javascript errors. Also, all the other javascript on the page works, also, the print dialogue is launched still.

Comment: @MikeC - added some pictures.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a CSS error.
You have display:none set twice.

Try changing the first two lines:

```
<div id="printthis" style="display:none;width:95%;">
<div style="border:2px groove black;">
```

...

If it is still not working, you can use the Bootstrap CSS that you imported.

1. Remove the javascript altogether if you like. (Then you can just use the browser's Print command.  No new window is needed).
2. Move the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">` into the `<head></head>`.  Stylesheets are generally supposed to go inside `<head>`.
3. You would apply class="visible-print" to items you want to show when printing.
4. You would apply class="hidden-print" to items you want to hide when printing.

Something like this:

```
<div class="hidden-print">
  stuff you don't want to print
</div>

<div id="printthis" class="visible-print">
  <div style="width:95%;border:2px groove black; margin:0 auto;">

  ...your table stuff
```

Comment: How would I call this print function with a button?

Comment: Also, this is only 1 print function out of 3 on the same page, so if I use visible-print on all of them, they will all combine to the same print page - which is not acceptable.

Comment: Although while working with this, I removed the two lines calling my bootstrap files, and it seems to have possibly fixed it.

Comment: In this case, keep the JS, but it looked like your real issue is that the printed div is set to display:none.  First just try taking off the second 'display:none'.

Comment: No, I had tried that initially because I thought the same thing, but it did the same thing either way. I guess it didn't like those bootstrap imports. Working now.

Comment: Odd, Bootstrap shouldn't do that.
If you just want the table styles, you can just copy that section of css into  your own css file, should be ok.

Comment: Nah I just quickly made some new ones. I just needed some key spacing bootstrap had and was being lazy at the time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was the imports to bootstrap inside the hidden div that it was printing from.

Basically, I turned:

```
<div id="printthis" style="display:none;width:95%;">
<div style="width:95%;border:2px groove black;display:none;">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/theme.css">
```

Into this:

```
<div id="printthis" style="display:none;width:95%;">
```

so cleaner code and now works on all browsers.